# Metric of a product of two metric spaces.

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a doubt on how to prove the triangle inequality for the metric $d$ defined on $X\times X$ (where $X=X_{1}\times X_{2}$ and $(X_{1},d_{1}), (X_{2},d_{2})$ are metric spaces) by $$d(x,y)=\sqrt{d_{1}(x_{1},y_{1})^{2}+d_{2}(x_{2},y_{2})^{2}}$$ where $x=(x_{1},x_{2})$ and $y=(y_{1},y_{2})$.

I have tried to apply the triangle inequality for each metric but this produces a quantity "greater" than what i want.
Any sugestions?

Comment: If at  first you don't succeed,
Try, try again ("Diamonds are forever").

Answer (score 0):

For convenience let $a=d_1(x_1,y_1)$, $b=d_1(x_1,z_1)$, $c=d_1(z_1,y_1)$, $u=d_2(x_2,y_2)$, $v=d_2(x_2,z_2)$, and $w=d_2(z_2,y_2)$; we know that $a\le b+c$ and $u\le v+w$, and we want to show that

$$\sqrt{a^2+u^2}\le\sqrt{b^2+v^2}+\sqrt{c^2+w^2}\,.\tag{1}$$

Lacking any brilliant ideas, we might do the obvious and square both sides, noting that we’ll have $(1)$ if we can show that

$$a^2+u^2\le b^2+v^2+c^2+w^2+2\sqrt{(b^2+v^2)(c^2+w^2)}\,.$$

We do know that $a^2\le b^2+c^2+2bc$ and $u^2\le v^2+w^2+2vw$, so

$$a^2+u^2\le b^2+c^2+v^2+w^2+2(bc+vw)\,,$$

and we’ll be done if we can show that

$$bc+vw\le\sqrt{(b^2+v^2)(c^2+w^2)}\,.$$

We’re still dealing with non-negative quantities, so we can square again and hope to show that

$$(bc+vw)^2\le(b^2+v^2)(c^2+w^2)\,,$$

i.e., that

$$b^2c^2+v^2w^2+2bcvw\le b^2c^2+v^2w^2+b^2w^2+v^2c^2\,.$$

And *that* reduces to showing that $2bcvw\le b^2w^2+v^2c^2$, which is easily done by a standard trick:

$$0\le(bw-vc)^2=b^2w^2+v^2c^2-2bcvw\,,$$

so $2bcvw\le b^2w^2+v^2c^2$.

This is very inelegant and could doubtless be done much more neatly, but it shows that a bit of intelligently directed tinkering can sometimes be good enough even if you don’t at first see just where you’re going.